# SVN accessing file outside trunk - avoid issues in tags and branches

Tags: svn, branch, file-structure

I am looking for advice about how to solve a file access issue between projects in an SVN repository.

Let's say that I have a `common.txt` file in project root (`/`), which is used by multiple projects. Examples are common settings, reusable snippets, etc. In the picture below is the recommended directory structure. Of course I can always deviate from it, but it seems practical and everybody is familiar with it. Directories `branches` or `tags` are at the same level as `trunk`, but below them are tag/branch names as directories, and therefore a file outside trunk - `/common.txt`  - can not be referenced with its relative path like '../../common.txt', because from the trunk it points to the root, but from the branches/tags it will point to the project directory (`calc` or `paint` in the example picture).

So what is the typical way to solve this issue?

- to introduce an additional level below `trunk`? It is not elegant...
- to create a shell variable which point to the project root and use that variable to reach `/common.txt`?  But in a different machine, with a different shell it might not exist, so some hookups might be needed (I've got no experience with them so far.)
- to create a link to `/common.txt` for every project and to reference this link in the code? It introduces an additional file: the link.

I would probably go with the last one, but I feel that there supposed to be some common knowledge, preferred way to do this, what I am not aware of, and I have not found in my searches.

[image: typical SVN directory tree]

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't mix physical and logical entities: "Projects" exist only in your brain, while SVN operate by "Repository", "Tree", "Directory", "Path". Your projects is just some subtree of SVN-repo
2. Select and follow one of known well-established tree-structures in SVN... and in *any* case you have not operate with objects below "root" of your tree, i.e - if you work with `.../trunk` you don't use any file lower than trunk

You **must** to read about SVN externals, understand concept and use it *properly*